# Which is more efficient ? A view created by java or a view in xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, performance, view

Which is more efficient way? IN ANDROID
If I create a button programically and same button is created with xml.Which will consume more memmory? Or both same?which will take more storage?

Comment: Use the one you (and your team) find more comfortable and convenient, the memory footprint does / should not matter to you. (they are probably identical anyway)

Answer (score 0):

View created in xml will render faster and it will have lesser load on memory as well as on processor. The storage used by it is negligible.